# How to get the address from HashMap array and convert it into LatLng??

Tags: java, android

Beginner here! How can i get the address from the jobs and convert it to LatLng and add it into markerPoints() array ?? Need help !

```
try {
            JSONObject jobj=jparser.makeHttpRequest(URL, "POST", params);
            success=jobj.getInt("success");
            s=jobj.getString("message");
            if(success==1){
                jobs=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
                JSONArray jAr=jobj.getJSONArray("routeplanning");
                for (int i = 0; i < jAr.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject job=jAr.getJSONObject(i);
                    HashMap<String , String> map=new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put("id",  job.getString("id"));
                    map.put("tripid", job.getString("tripid"));
                    map.put("parcelid", job.getString("parcelid"));
                    map.put("date", job.getString("date"));
                    map.put("senderid", job.getString("senderid"));
                    map.put("driverid", job.getString("driverid"));
                    map.put("pickupaddress", job.getString("pickupaddress"));
                    map.put("deliveraddress", job.getString("deliveraddress"));




                    jobs.add(map);
                 ;

                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Do you want to geocode a string address (e.g. pickupaddress) to coordinates? If yes, take a look at the Geocoder https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html

Comment: @peshkira yea.problem solved.. thanks!